# Vue js - Property or method "recipe" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Вот такая ошибка:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "recipe" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
<template>
    <div class="container recipes">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" :v-for="recipe in recipes_arr">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="/img/header-background.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Recipe picture">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"> </h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            recipes_arr: [],
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/api/showAll')
        .then(response => { 
            this.recipes_arr = response.data;
            console.log(response.data); // Works
            console.log(this.recipes_arr[0].title); // Works
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед v-for не нужно ставить двоеточие.

```
<div class="col-md-6" v-for="recipe, key in recipes_arr" :key="key"> ...code...</div>
```

Про key читайте там же, в документации

Comment: Нет, нужно, это отдельный .vue компонент

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html - ссылка на оф. документацию

Comment: https://ibb.co/xjP6SCT

Comment: https://ibb.co/mDXzGTB